# how to find API value to html table once the API call is made

Tags: javascript, html, database, api, binding

I am trying to call an API and once data comes I need to update the table where I am using a jQuery data table

I am able to see the data from he API in the browser console, but I'm not sure how to bind the data to the table.

```html
<h1 class="text-center">Student Details</h1>

<table id="maintable" class="display compact cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>TOTAL MARKS</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Sam</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mark.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datatables.mark.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var apiUrl = 'http:localhost:5000/studenDetails?page=1&limit=2';
  fetch(apiUrl).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(data => {
    // Work with JSON data here
    console.log(data);
  }).catch(err => {
    // Do something for an error here
  });
</script>
```